# Problema con Variables Array dentro de un Include PHP

Tags: php, php5

Estoy desarrollando un archivo maestro que me incluya todos los archivos (Clases, funciones, etc.).

**La inclusión automática la realizo de la siguiente manera:**

```
$dir = "assets/php";

$funciones = [];
function includes ($dir){
    if ($gestor = opendir($dir)) {
        while (false !== ($entrada = readdir($gestor))) {
            if ($entrada != "." && $entrada != "..") {
                if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$entrada)){
                    includes ($dir.'/'.$entrada);
                }else{

                    include_once ($dir.'/'.$entrada);
                }

            }
        }
        closedir($gestor);
    }
    }
    includes ($dir);
    var_dump($funciones);
```

Con eso incluyo todos los archivos que estén dentro de ese directorio y subdirectorios.

En el primer archivo almaceno un array con unos parámetros.
**archivo1.php**:

```
    $funciones[count($funciones)] = [
    'Function_Name' =>  'WS_funcion1',
    'Operation'     =>  'fn_Datos',
    'Require_Name'  =>  'Datos_Require',
    'Require_Data'  =>  [[ 'name' => 'dato1', 'type' => 'string']],
    'Response_Name' =>  'Datos_Response',
    'Response_Data' =>  [
                            [   'name' => 'datosArray',
                                'type' => 'array',
                                'data' =>   [
                                                [
                                                    'name' => 'Datos',
                                                    'data'=> [
                                                        [
                                                            'name' => 'DatoRespuesta1','type' => 'string'
                                                        ],
                                                        [
                                                            'name' => 'DatoRespuesta2','type' => 'string'
                                                        ],
                                                        [
                                                            'name' => 'DatoRespuesta3','type' => 'int'
                                                        ]
                                                    ]
                                                ]
                                            ]
                            ]
                        ]
];
```

Cuando hago el **var_dump($funciones);** Simplemente me retorna `array(0) { }`.

Si incluyo el archivo manualmente `include 'assets/php/subdirectory1/archivo1.php';` Si funciona, pero quiero aclarar que la inclusión si se realiza ya que lo probé con una variable string sencilla y esa si me sigue manteniendo el valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la variable `$funciones` no esta definida dentro la función ya que esta en el ámbito global.

Puedes usar [`global`](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php) dentro la función para solucionar el problema:

```
function includes( $dir ) {

  global $funciones;

  // Resto de código
}
```

Comment: Disculpa era con "include_once" , ya actualice el código, sobre tu respuesta, lo probé y solo me imprime el texto mas no me incluye el código.

Comment: @Andrés - Ok... he cambiado la respuesta.. mira a ver si te sirve asi

Comment: Funciona completamente Gracias.